# How to transfer music and files from Ubuntu 13.10 to Android 4.3?

Tags: 13.10, android

I'm trying to transfer files and music from my computer with Ubuntu 13.10 to my Samsung smartphone S3 Android version 4.3 with no success. Can someone please help me and guide me through the steps to do so?

Comment: Are you trying to transfer files via usb cable?

Answer (score 1):

Install Rhythmbox or Banshee from Software Center and when the phone is plugged in via USB they should detect the device and allow you to directly drag and drop music into the device from within the application.

NOTE: You may need to place your device in USB Mass Storage Mode first. When you connect the cable you should have a tick box or menu item that allows you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution is to use google play music. I've found it to be pretty seamless. You can simply upload your music to the cloud and stream it from the Internet remotely. You may want to check it out.